# Constraint Validation Exception on Transient Variable

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-data-jpa

My entity class extends a class that contains a variable that is annotated transient but has also been annotated with `@NotBlank` and when I try to save I keep getting a constraint violation exception.

I have even tried to set the data before I save but to no avail.

here is my entity class below.

```
@ToString
@MappedSuperclass
@ApiModel
@Data
public class TokenInitiationRequest {

    @Transient
    @NotBlank(message = "data key can not be blank, i.e. can not be empty or null")
    private String dataKey;
}

@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Data
public class TokenTransaction extends TokenInitiationRequest{
    ... removed for brevity ...
}
```

how do I save my token transaction object without getting a constraint violation exception, besides the variable is transient, I would expect it to be skipped.